# What's the term for the information you gather from someone before deciding to bring them in for an interview?

Tags: word-choice, expressions, synonyms, terminology

What is another word for the information you gather from someone before deciding to bring them in for an interview? (Salary Requirements, Commuting Restrictions, etc.)

What I'm trying to say is:

> Before we bring in any potential consultants to meet, we like to begin with a brief phone conversation to gather _______.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You could call it [preliminary information](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/preliminary). It's a bit stiff, but that might be what the occasion calls for if you're talking about a job interview. I would wait for a few more people to chime in before deciding if this is the best answer to your question.

Answer (score 1):

It is called ***screening information*** in Human Resources jargon. It is sometimes used as *pre-screening information* or *pre-employment screening information*. The actual screening process might be more comprehensive depending on the company.

If the information is about academic and professional background, the common term is *background information*.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are *qualifying* the candidate for suitability.

You are also *filtering* (or *filtering out*) consultants.

A more colorful term is that you are [winnowing](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Winnowing) consultants, that is, separating the suitable from the unsuitable.

As to the information itself (and to fill in your blank) you might say that you are gathering *intel* or gathering *intelligence* on your potential consultants. You might combine one of these words with any of the previous paragraphs.

> I am gathering *qualifying intelligence* on the candidates.
>
> We need to gather some *filtering intel* on the candidates.

Answer (score 0):

I'd personally go with **background information**. This is in line with an interviewer saying "First, I'd like to get a little background information."